# Condition for for Manifolds dual to functions

Tags: reference-request, manifolds

What is the condition (locally compact/paracompact/Hausdorff/second countable?) for the following familiar statement:

---

The category of (finite dimensional smooth) manifolds is contravariant isomorphic to the full subcategory of algebras (given by global functions) 
$$
Manifolds\to Algebras \quad M\mapsto C^\infty(M).
$$

A little explanation why certain condition needed are highly appreciated.